# Create JSON list of JSON objects

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, json-schema-validator

I've built a REST Service in Spring Boot that accepts `JSON` being `POST`ed to the endpoints. I'm validating the `JSON` `POST`ed against a `JSON` schema using `json-schema-validator`. I get error messages in `JSON` when there is validation errors. I want to send the error message back to the client in `JSON`. The issue I have is that I get each error message in its own `JSON` object. This is not a problem it there is only one error message but I would like to have have just one `JSON` message with all error message if there is more than one error. Currently I get the error message in a `ProcessingReport` object. Iterating over the `ProcessingReport` I'm able to get each `ProcessingMessage` that I can convert to `JSON`.

```
for(ProcessingMessage message : report ) {
                  message.asJson();
            }
```

Each error messages looks like this:

```
{
    "level": "error",
    "schema": {
      "loadingURI": "#",
      "pointer": "/properties/parameterDateAdjusted"
    },
    "instance": {
      "pointer": "/parameterDateAdjusted"
    },
    "domain": "validation",
    "keyword": "format",
    "attribute": "date-time",
    "message": "string \"2017-02-29T23:59:00Z\" is invalid against requested date format(s) [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.[0-9]{1,12}Z]",
    "value": "2017-02-29T23:59:00Z",
    "expected": [
      "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
      "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.[0-9]{1,12}Z"
    ]
  }
```

I would like to have multiple error message looking something like this:

```
{
  "error": 1,
  "message": {
    "level": "error",
    "schema": {
      "loadingURI": "#",
      "pointer": "/properties/parameterDateAdjusted"
    },
    "instance": {
      "pointer": "/parameterDateAdjusted"
    },
    "domain": "validation",
    "keyword": "format",
    "attribute": "date-time",
    "message": "string \"2017-02-29T23:59:00Z\" is invalid against requested date format(s) [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.[0-9]{1,12}Z]",
    "value": "2017-02-29T23:59:00Z",
    "expected": [
      "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
      "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.[0-9]{1,12}Z"
    ]
  },
  "error": 2,
  "message": {
    "level": "error",
    "schema": {
      "loadingURI": "#",
      "pointer": "/properties/parameterDateUnadjusted"
    },
    "instance": {
      "pointer": "/parameterDateUnadjusted"
    },
    "domain": "validation",
    "keyword": "format",
    "attribute": "date-time",
    "message": "string \"2010-11-31T00:00:00Z\" is invalid against requested date format(s) [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.[0-9]{1,12}Z]",
    "value": "2010-11-31T00:00:00Z",
    "expected": [
      "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
      "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.[0-9]{1,12}Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

What would be the best way of doing this? Can I create a `List` of `JSON` object like `List<Jsonnode>` and the that converted to one `Jsonnode`? Or is the some way I can concatenate the `JSON` error messages?

Comment: Did you already try to return `List<JsonNode>` in your method and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can just return a list of objects, Spring will map it to a JSON array.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<ErrorWrapper> getSomething() throws IOException {
    List<JsonNode> errorNodes = new ArrayList<>();
    errorNodes.add(new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode());
    errorNodes.add(new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode());

    return IntStream.range(0, errorNodes.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> new ErrorWrapper(i + 1, errorNodes.get(i)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And

```
public class ErrorWrapper {
    private int error;
    private JsonNode message;

    public ErrorWrapper(int error, JsonNode message) {
        this.error = error;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public JsonNode getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Returns

```
[
    {
        "error": 1,
        "message": { }
    },
    {
        "error": 2,
        "message": { }
    }
]
```

Comment: I would prefer to get  `{"error":1, "message":{JSON_FROM_VALIDATION}, "error":2, "message":{JSON_FROM_VALIDATION}}`. I guess I would need to create the node for error 1 and error 2 and then add the messages from the validation.

Comment: @g3blv Yeah, if that's your goal I would create a POJO wrapper around each error node or loop over the nodes and enrich them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I took parts of Luciano answers and came up with this:

```
List<JsonErrorMessage> jsonErrorMessages = new ArrayList<>();
            int i = 0;
            for (ProcessingMessage message : report) {
                i++;
                jsonErrorMessage.setErrorNumber(i);
                jsonErrorMessage.setMessage(message.asJson());
                jsonErrorMessages.add(jsonErrorMessage);
            }

            return (new ResponseEntity(jsonErrorMessages, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
```

It creates the response I want. Not sure if there is any issues with it that I'm not aware about.